# Can't connect to device via RFCOMM because 'Resource Busy'

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth, pyserial, lego-mindstorms

I am trying to open a connection with a Lego EV3 brick, whose serial port is /dev/tty.EV3-SerialPort, I am on mac 10.6.8. I get a Resource busy when I do this, yet when I use other API's to connect (writing to the serial port not through pyserial) it does not show an error. I would like to find a way to get around this error. Why is it busy, all other bluetooth applications are disabled. Here is my code:

test.py:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.EV3-SerialPort', 19200, timeout=1)  # open first serial port
ser.close()
ser.open()
time.sleep(1)
ser.close()
print "closed"
```

Here is the error it outputs:

```
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
ser.open()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 289, in open
self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/tty.EV3-SerialPort'
```

A popup also presents itself saying:

```
A Bluetooth serial failure has occurred.
Failed to open an RFCOMM serial channel.
Check if authentication needs to be enabled in your device
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to communicate with the EV3 by just opening the serial port as a file rather than using the serial module.

```
with open('/dev/tty.EV3-SerialPort', 'w+', 0) as bt:
```

See https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4257/3498 for a complete example.

Comment: I will look into this, this is what many libraries use. I have one question, is there a similar way to capture incoming packets(coming from the ev3)? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Thanks! Just tried using `incoming = bt.read()` and it threw the error `IOError: File not open for reading`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the manual ;-)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

'w+' should do the trick.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot, i knew that. I thought it was an EV3 related problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used exactly your example and works to me, check out (in my case the connection name is different as shown below:).

```
EV3 = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.EV3-N1-SerialPort', 19200, timeout=1)
```